# How to get list of journals in a discipline within a specified range of impact factors?

Tags: publications, ieee, impact-factor

I am looking for journals about A with impact factor between X and Y. Is there any way to find that on IEEE web site?

Comment: InCites (from [Thomson-Reuters](https://jcr.incites.thomsonreuters.com/JCRJournalHomeAction.action?SID=A2-Ozxxlm7GZeoEPJWrDKz559m6NuhQx2BM4TZ-18x2dfoMxxOP36kj4ILyGpmx2Fh9wgx3Dx3DLFELtdNx2FjyUBAHSFDOeaFAx3Dx3D-9vvmzcndpRgQCGPd1c2qPQx3Dx3D-wx2BJQh9GKVmtdJw3700KssQx3Dx3D&SrcApp=IC2LS&Init=Yes))  can handle this kind of search.

Comment: If you want to use only IEEE websites, probably you should manually go to each journal's homepage, e.g., here's IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory's page http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/RecentIssue.jsp?punumber=18 and it shows its impact factor right there. If you want some sort of list, this seems to be the closest you can get: http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/journmag/journalcitations.html Of course, it's a lot easier if you have access to JCR or other similar service. If Eiganfactor/article influence score is ok, this will help http://www.eigenfactor.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Web of Science Journal Citation Reports](https://jcr.incites.thomsonreuters.com/JCRJournalHomeAction.action?SID=A2-Ozxxlm7GZeoEPJWrDKz559m6NuhQx2BM4TZ-18x2dfoMxxOP36kj4ILyGpmx2Fh9wgx3Dx3DLFELtdNx2FjyUBAHSFDOeaFAx3Dx3D-9vvmzcndpRgQCGPd1c2qPQx3Dx3D-wx2BJQh9GKVmtdJw3700KssQx3Dx3D&SrcApp=IC2LS&Init=Yes) provides lists of journals on a topic along with a range of citation-based metrics, including impact factor. It's straight forward to sort such lists by impact factor and then extract journals within a range.

Many universities have subscriptions to Web of Science Journal Citation Reports. So check out your university library.